# Having two vectors is there a nicer way to test if one is included in another?

Tags: r, vector, string-matching

Given two vectors:

```
x = c('a','b')
lookup = c('a','c','d','e','f')
```

test if each element in `x` is present in `lookup`. One way of doing it:

```
all(!is.na(match(x, lookup)))
```

I find this solution a bit verbose for R and wonder if there is better/shorter version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%in%` does this:

```
all(x %in% lookup)
## [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Can also use `setdiff`. See the associated help page for other set operations.

```
setdiff(x,lookup)
[1] "b"
> as.logical(length( setdiff(x,lookup) ) )
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I find `as.logical(length(...))` an opaque way to test whether the vector is empty: I would prefer `length(setdiff(x,lookup))>0` ...

Comment: I think I pick up that manner of thinking by reading source code that looks like `if ( length(x) ){do something}`.